# Serialize and save 3d object with Rajawali

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, rajawali, rajawalivr

I try to serialize and save (local) the 3d object with rajawali,

I try with compile version ;

`org.rajawali3d:rajawali:1.0.186-SNAPSHOT@aar`

and

`org.rajawali3d:rajawali:1.1.970`

but I haven't any access to "ExportType"

I try to change "ExportType" to

```
exporter.export("myBaseObject3Dname", new AExporter() { 
@Override public void export() { } }.getClass());
```

but it does not work.

I get the bug:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: rajawalynew, PID: 5811
>   org.rajawali3d.util.MeshExporter$ExporterException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: []
>   at org.rajawali3d.util.MeshExporter.export(MeshExporter.java:103)
>   at org.rajawali3d.util.MeshExporter.export(MeshExporter.java:60)